# Obter route.name através de HttpContextBase

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Tenho rotas mapeadas em minha aplicação:

```
context.MapRoute("Home.Index", "home/{action}/{parameter}", 
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", parameter = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

escrevi um atributo que herda de: `AuthorizeAttribute`, que decora alguns métodos.  Quando executado o método do atributo:

```
protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext){ }
```

gostaria de obter o `name` da rota `Home.Index` através do objeto: `httpContext.`

Isso é possível?

Comment: Naturalmente não é possível. Existem alternativas, mas não acho que alguma valha a pena. Por que você precisa do nome da rota?

Comment: @LINQ Porque acabo fazendo um controle de permissões baseado no prefixo da rota. Esse controle é dinâmico e tudo é gerado a partir disso: menus, acessos e etc. Precisava então saber qual é a rota registrada, se houver, pro método em questão...